# How to show multiple attachments based on attribute fields in pop-up (ArcGIS Portal)?

Tags: web-applications, attachment, arcgis, portal

I am new to portal to this is a little bit confusing for me.

I am creating a interactive map app to showcase different buildings along campus. I want to show images and documents per building (based on what they current look like and what they used to look like). I have two columns: 'Historic'. and 'Current.' Each historic and current have multiple attachments as well.

Now my question is, how do I show historic and current in the pop-up? Is it possible to have within the pop-up that says the following:
Historic:
image1.png
image2.png
image3.pdf

Current: 
image1.png
image2.png
image3.pdf

What I did so far was that I created a feature class that shows the building, created a version feature class, went into editor and added attachments through the attachment manager.

Now my next step is to publish the service. In which step do I go ahead and created two fields for the images and documents?

Comment: You will more likely find someone who can answer this question if you ask it at gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT transformations will do this.**

- First jump into \Metadata\Stylesheets,
  find the "defaultTemplate.xsl", and make a copy.
- Next you will need to modify the xsl to display what you want.
  Unfortunately it can involve a bit of trial and error.Check out http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/xslt-transformation.htm for more info. (Specifically for attachments (images), target "FieldsDoc/Attachments/Attachment")
- Once you modify it, you can test it on a layer in ArcMap by going to
  the layer properties>HTML Popup, then choose "As a formatted page
  based on XSL template". Load your xsl file, then try clicking on a
  feature to see the results.

Word of warning, ArcMap can be odd with refreshing, so you may need to close out and reopen at times to view your popup changes.

Once you are good to go in ArcMap, simply publish your service, and your web map should respect the pop up template.